# Recommend me a productivity/workflow tool

Tags: software-recommendation

Can anyone recommend me a productivity/workflow tool that does the following?

- I would like it to be task based
- I would like to be able to set:

  - a due-date
  - priority
  - status (for example: started, paused, waiting for input, finished, cancelled)
- I would like to be able to link directly to one or several emails in my email program (OS X Mail.app or Thunderbird preferred)
- I would like to write notes about each task
- I would like to be able to add attachments (documents and images)
- Some calendar integration would be nice

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions: http://superuser.com/questions/220608/recommend-me-a-productivity-workflow-tool

Comment: @mankoff I can't close as a dupe of a question on a different site. Once we launch and there's a migration path, the questions could be migrated and merged, but until then it's OK to ask on both sites.

Comment: Nice suggestions everyone. It'll be a while before I can pick a "winner" as I'll have to try the apps before I decide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe [Things](http://culturedcode.com/things/) does all that. I use it. I like it.

I don’t know about thunderbird “linking” but with Mail.app it works. You can “drag” a mail onto a task or things to create a new one. Same with documents.

Comment: Extra info - Licence is personal so you can use it on more than one computer. iPad and iPhone apps purchased separately, for now only one computer can sync with the iPad/iPhone version.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for [OmniFocus](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnifocus/), which does (if I recall) everything you want, has a system-wide modal "inbox" tool as well as synchronizable iPad and iPhone apps.

Their price point is ridiculously high in my opinion, but people are fanatical about it.

Comment: that's like using a sledge hammer to hang a picture on a wall.

Comment: @Epaga, I disagree. Nifle asked for "a productivity/workflow tool," rather than for a simple tasks list. OmniFocus is a productivity tool which *certainly may* be overkill for their needs, but that's for them to decide. OmniFocus sells themselves even for accomplishing household tasks (based on their "contexts").

Comment: i agree that it's a good recommendation since it's one of the standard programs out there. and i also agree it's ridiculously overpriced. ;)

Answer (score 2):

The [Hit List](http://www.potionfactory.com/thehitlist/) also does all this. I'm currently using it. It offers sub-tasks and sub-folders so it is more inline with OmniOutlier than Things (which does not offer sub-folders).

It's currently in Beta, which is nice because it's free.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to take a look at [Process](http://www.jumsoft.com/process/) ([Manual in PDF](http://www.jumsoft.com/pdf/manuals/Process_User_Manual.pdf)). It’s cheaper than Things and OmniFocus.

<sub>**note**: *I’m adding this 2nd answer so people can vote at their discretion.*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your description, you might like Kanban Tool (https://kanbantool.com/). It is task-based, you can add due dates, set priorities and change the status of the task. You can add attachments. It also has a time tracking feature (I personally find it very helpful) and is easy to use. There's a free trial, so you can always test it and see for yourself whether you like it or not.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Are you involved in this software or company in any way?  I'm just asking because this question hasn't been updated or answered in 8 years.